# c# mvc 4 EF 5 get dbset from dbcontext without knowing the tabel name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I have a `Users` entity set and a `Administrators` entity set. I want to get a list of items that can be a `IEnumerable<Users>` or a `IEnumerable<Administrators>` from the DBContext

i want to be able to do

```
Type dbContextType = db.GetType();

Type tableType = dbContextType.GetProperty("users", 
    BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance
).PropertyType;

var items = db.Database.SqlQuery(tableType , "SELECT * FROM users");
```

the problem is that tableType is a typeof `DbSet` and i need a typeof `Users`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplier than i thought

```
Type typeDB = Type.GetType("Models.User");

var items = db.Database.SqlQuery(typeDB, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE IdUser = '"+id+"'");
```

items is now a `System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalSqlQuery` witch has a Enumerator with our objects. Problem is that we can't send this object to a strongly typed view.

Therefor we have to cast it.If we don't know the class we want it to be cast to , then we can cast it to object type. And the view we are going to send it to will do the specific cast to the strongly typed object.

```
return View("Users", items.Cast< object >().ElementAt(0));
```

Now we have one controller that we can use for multiple strongly typed views.